# Postgres: using timestamps for pagination

Tags: postgresql

I have table with `created` (timestamptz) property. Now, i need to create pagination based on timestamp, because while user is watching first page, new items could be submitted into this table, which will make data inconsistent in case if i'll use `OFFSET` for pagination.

So, the question is: should i keep `created` type as `timestamptz` or it's better to convert it into integer (unix, e.g. `1472031802812`). If so, is there any disadvantages? Also, atm i have `now()` as default value in `created` - is there alternative function to create unix timestamp?

Comment: There's no advantage in keeping datetime as an integer timestamp. Actually this only complicates things. For example imagine a query "give me all since the begining of the month" on integers. Just don't. `timestamp` is exactly what you need, use it.

Comment: @freakish, Thank you! if i'd have integers, i would just say `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE created < customTimeStamp`. But in case if i use `timestamptz` it looks like i'll be converting each item in table to make sure, it's at least few milliseconds later than specified timestamp. Am i wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. `timestampz` does support `<` operator. Why would you convert anything? I don't see a point in doing that.

Comment: Precision of `timestampz` is **exactly** the same as precision of unix timestamp. Actually `timestampz` **is** unix integer timestamp under the hood. The type just gives you more datetime related features. All you have to do is properly create `customTimeStamp` (to include milliseconds for example) in your query and you'll be fine.

Comment: ok, then could you, please, show me an example, how to do something like this: `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE created < customTimeStamp`? `customTimeStamp` here is the date, when the last queried item was created and now i just need to select next, say, 10 rows, which were created later.

Comment: Obviously `customTimestamp` has to be the last timestamp fetched by previous query. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me rewrite things from comments to my answer. You want to use `timestamp` type instead of `integer` simply because that's exactly what it was designed for. Doing manual convertions between timestamp integers and `timestamp` objects is just a pain and you gain nothing. And you will need it eventually for more complex datetime based queries.

To answer a question about pagination. You simply do a query

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE created < lastTimestamp
ORDER BY created DESC
LIMIT 30
```

If it is first query then you set say `lastTimestamp = '3000-01-01'`. Otherwise you set `lastTimestamp = last_query.last_row.created`.

---

*Optimization*

Note that if the table is big then `ORDER BY created DESC` might not be efficient (especially if called parallely with different ranges). In this case you can use moving "time windows", for example:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE
    created < lastTimestamp
    AND created >= lastTimestamp - interval '1 day'
```

The `1 day` interval is picked arbitrarly (tune it to your needs). You can also sort results in the app.

If results is not empty then you update (in your app)

```
lastTimestamp = last_query.last_row.created
```

(assuming you've done sorting, otherwise you take `min(last_query.row.created)`)

If results is empty then you repeat the query with `lastTimestamp = lastTimestamp - interval '1 day'` until you fetch something. Also you have to stop if `lastTimestamp` becomes to low, i.e. when it is lower then any other timestamp in the table (which has to be prefetched).

All of that is under some assumptions for inserts:

1. `new_row.created >= any_row.created` and
2. `new_row.created ~ current_time`
3. The distribution of `new_row.created` is more or less uniform

Assumption 1 ensures that pagination results in consistent data while assumption 2 is only needed for the default `3000-01-01` date. Assumption 3 is to make sure that you don't have big empty gaps when you have to issue many empty queries.

Comment: Thank you! one question: if i'll create index based on the `created`, will `DESC` still not be efficient?

Comment: @stkvtflw If we are talking about hundreds of millions of rows, then yes. But before you pick any strategy benchmark.

Comment: sorry for bothering you again, but i have one more very last question) How do i convert unix timestamp WITH MILLISECONDS into postgres-acceptable-timestamptz?

Comment: @stkvtflw One way would be to cast it manually `SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' + 982384720 * INTERVAL '1 second';` (taken from the docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/functions-datetime.html ). I suggest doing the conversion on the app level though.

Comment: If you have multiple rows with the same timestamp, then some data may get skipped.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
   select extract(epoch from now())::integer as unix_time
```

Comment: looks complicated) I mean, if i'd have integers, i would just say `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE created < customTimeStamp`. But in this case it looks like i'll be converting each item in table to make sure, it's at least few milliseconds later than specified timestamp. Am i wrong?