# Convert unix timestamp with milliseconds into postgres-readable timestamptz

Tags: javascript, postgresql

Is there simple way to convert a date formatted like this: `1471866155422` into date formatted like this: `2016-08-24 15:23:31.949284+03`.

I need this, because i have unix timestamps in client-side js app, and i need to implement pagination with PostgreSQL database based on `timestamptz`.

I assume this is good solution for pagination based on this question: [Postgres: using timestamps for pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39119783/postgres-using-timestamps-for-pagination?noredirect=1#comment65587379_39119783)

Comment: all solutions i've found are ignoring milliseconds in the unix timestamp, but this is critically important in my case

Comment: I do not think you have 949284 milliseconds in your timestamp

Answer (score 0):

This works for my Chrome in Holland. Not sure if the toString() does the same for you

```js
function pad(num) {
  return String("0"+num).slice(-2);
}
function toPost(ts) {
  var d = new Date(ts);
  var time = d.toString().split(d.getFullYear()+" ")[1].split("(")[0].slice(0,-3)
  time = time.replace(/ GMT/,"."+d.getMilliseconds())
  return d.getFullYear()+"-"+pad(d.getMonth()+1)+"-"+pad(d.getDate())+" "+time;
}
alert(toPost(new Date().getTime())+"\n"+toPost(1471866155422)+"\n"+"2016-08-24 15:23:31.949284+03");
```